# Ubuntu 18.04 window flickering/strobing white for specific applications

Tags: 18.04, drivers, graphics, skype, flicker

I've been having lots of graphical issues with specific applications on Ubuntu 18.04 using my Dell Latitude 7490. For instance on GitKraken:

[image: Example of application that goes... whatever that is]

The same thing happens on:

- Zoom
- Slack
- Signal
- Skype
- Discord
- Telegram (I think)
- Chrome
- Chromium

I think this is giving me random crashes after some point (where my session just closes and I lose everything that's opened, but the RAM doesn't lower). I'd like to fix the graphical issues first and hope that it fixes the random crashes.

I get the feeling there's an underlying cause there, some software thingy, a driver issue, but I have no idea where to look or what relevant information to give. I thought about:

```bsh
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)

$ hostnamectl
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-64-generic
    Architecture: x86-64

$ glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
```

It might be relevant that I'm using `i3` and `compton`, though it happens on a regular Gnome session and with `compton` not running.

Comment: This is not a solution (I don't have enough brownie points to add a comment) but may give you more clues as to the cause of the problem. Check the drivers with: `sudo lshw -c video` Check for any errors that mention the drivers. `dmesg | grep fail` If the problem is seen on a single monitor then that points to a driver problem. For diagnostic purposes you could also try logging into Gnome display manager rather than Ubuntu Wayland.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The first command returned what I expected, namely `Intel` driver: `product: Intel Corporation; description: VGA compatible controller; configuration: driver=i915 latency=0`.

And the second, well, there are some issues about getting the temperature but otherwise, there are two things that did catch my eye, cf. [here](http://pastebin.fr/83651). I'll try and see about these!

Answer (score 0):

Again this is not a solution, I am still unable to comment.

You could try reinstalling the driver

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Shutdown, disconnect the cable. Power on. When you log in try and select one of the other display managers (click on the cog to select an alternative), this is to rule out that it isn't the display manager at fault. Then connect the display cable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was hardware acceleration. There are lots of information already online regarding how to deactivate it system-wise. I fixed these issues (apart from Zoom which is still flickering) by following the answer from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408582/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-in-linux). Note that the other solutions mentioning creating a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and putting an `AccelMethod` to `sna` didn't fix the issue for me.